# Creating a new instance of class then calling method with arg Java

Tags: java, reflection

I'm trying to create a new instance of a class "ImageViewer" then call a method called "OpenFile" which has an argument of another class "OFImage" this must all be done in the "OpenFile" method in the orginal instance of "ImageViewer"

I looked into reflection however just keep getting errors

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: please post your code and the exception stacktrace

Comment: Show your code and error message. Why reflection? Sounds like you're making things more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to create a new instance of a class "ImageViewer" then call a method called "OpenFile" which has an argument of another class "OFImage" this must all be done in the "OpenFile" method in the orginal instance of "ImageViewer"

Okay. So let's create a new `ImageViewer` :

```
ImageViewer iV = new ImageViewer();
```

Then you call the `OpenFile` method. Keep in mind that Java naming convention dictates that the first word of a method always starts with a lower case letter.

```
iV.openFile( // Some code );
```

Now you want to pass the class type `OFImage` into the `OpenFile` method. So you can pass it in a `Class` object:

```
iv.openFile(OFImage.class);
```

This will send an instance of a `Class` object, with all the class details of an `OFImage`.

Alternatively if you meant to pass it an instance of an `OFImage` object, you can use an anonymous object:

```
iv.openFile(new OFImage(// necessary parameters));
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help, however your right. I was making it way to complicated. Had a little break then went back to it and got it with your help Chris

Comment: Ah I'm glad to hear that. Be sure to mark this as the correct answer if this is the one you preferred :)